# Input file: How to display the name of a file even after refresh?

Tags: javascript, html

I notice that the `value` attributes doesn't make the input file display anything:

```
<input
  name="floorplan"
  value="file.jpg"
  type="file">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fy206y41/

What's the attribute that I need to use so I can see `file.jpg` even after refresh? (And get overidden if a file is uploaded?

Comment: @chalarangelo No, I just want to display the name of the file.

Comment: It is not simple as you imagine.. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's not possible to pre-populate a file input, for obvious security reasons. If you want to preview the last image that a user uploaded in this context, you can just load it into the page as an image.